# How can I include down more than one level in a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public partial class Exam
{
    public Exam()
    {
        this.Objectives = new List<Objective>();
    }
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Objective> Objectives { get; set; }
}
public partial class Objective

    public Objective()
    {
        this.ObjectiveDetails = new List<ObjectiveDetail>();
    }

    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> ObjectiveDetails { get; set; }
}

public partial class ObjectiveDetail
{
    public ObjectiveDetail()
    {
        this.SubTopics = new List<SubTopic>();
    }
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Objective Objective { get; set; }

}
```

I created the following to get the Exam and Objective data:

```
        var exam = _examsRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(e => e.Name == name)
            .Include(e => e.Objectives)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

But how can I also include the ObjectiveDetails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
var exam = _examsRepository.GetAll()
    .Where(e => e.Name == name)
    .Include(e => e.Objectives)
    .Include(e => e.Objectives.Select(o => o. ObjectiveDetails))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

[MSDN article on loading related entities.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much. I will check this out now. Maybe later I will have another questions as I realize if this works okay then I will need to get the data in a sorted order. I will accept very soon.